# Qt 5.9.1 Android Publishing Store , OpenSSL Vulnerabilities Rejection

Tags: android, qt, security, openssl

I'm having an issue about publishing my android application to the Android Store,

> OpenSSL
>   The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep search for:
>
> \$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"

Afterwards, I've tried both building my own OpenSSL libraries according to [Official Qt instructions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html) and using prebuilt libraries given in [here](https://github.com/ph4r05/android-openssl)
but the result was the same. If anyone explains me what and how should I do, I would be grateful.

Comment: https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md

Answer (score 0):

You need newer OpenSSL libraries to get in play store.
I use 1.0.2k and they are accepted by google.

First make sure you have linked the right libs in your .pro file.

P.S.: change the paths to the right ones. And don't forget to run qmake and clean build after that.

```
contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = \
        $$PWD/../../Android/openssl-1.0.2k/libcrypto.so \
        $$PWD/../../Android/openssl-1.0.2k/libssl.so         
}

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,x86) {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = \
        $$PWD/../../OpenSSL/libcrypto.so \
        $$PWD/../../OpenSSL/libssl.so
}
```

I have uploaded my compiled OpenSSL 1.0.2k for armeabi-v7a [here](https://xplatforms.de/openssl-1.0.2k-libs-armeabi-v7a.tar.gz)

Comment: @john whitegun, has it worked for you? If so, consider to mark the answer, thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've already done that kind of solutions. In fact, the problem was not about whether apk file contains .so files or not. It was about the included OpenSSL file was not appropriate for my application. I've solve that issue by building my own .so files by setting up right options (like ndk version) before building .so files from source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user like me, please consider the setup Linux VM first. After creating your VM, install ndk which you already use in your project.

Follow the instructions given by Qt, [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html)

Make sure that you have entered right NDK version, Android build platform and other thing given in instruction.

After I've changed .so files with my own .so files, I republished my app to store and it is accepted without any warning.